# I'm trying to use VpnManagementAgent - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime

I simply copied and pasted the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854770/is-there-a-way-of-getting-connectionstatus-from-ivpnprofile-in-a-uwp-application):

```
#include <..\cppwinrt\winrt\windows.networking.vpn.h>
using namespace winrt::Windows::Networking::Vpn;

int wmain()
{   VpnManagementAgent vpn;
    auto profiles = vpn.getProfilesAsync().get();
    wprintf(L"Found %d profiles\n", profiles.Size());
    for (auto vp : profiles)
    {
        wprintf(L"Found profile %s\n", vp.ProfileName().c_str());
    }}
```

I know I've not initialized the windows runtime but that has nothing to do with the error I'm getting:

`so.cpp(7): error C2039: 'getProfilesAsync': is not a member of 'winrt::Windows::Networking::Vpn::VpnManagementAgent'`

I've done my research and there is definitely `getProfilesAsync` in `windows.networking.vpn.h` however I don't know how to reach it.

Comment: There seems to be a [`GetProfilesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn.vpnmanagementagent.getprofilesasync#Windows_Networking_Vpn_VpnManagementAgent_GetProfilesAsync) function, but no `getProfilesAsync`. Remember that C++ (and C++/CLI which you're using) is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I honestly thought the library was broken. I knew that but since I was copying over from another question I assumed it was all fine.

Comment: You likely copied from the javascript samples. The APIs as projected into JavaScript are "re-cased" to match expectations for that language as part of how they're projected.